# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "The": syntax error/Parameterizing sql

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have been receiving the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "The": syntax error
```

After troubleshooting I have determined the cause of it being an apostrophe(') in a books title. I have read that I need to parameterize the sql but I am having troubles doing it. The code in question:

```
#Connect to database
top_ten_db = connect('top_ten.db')

#Retrieve view of database
db_view = top_ten_db.cursor()

#Insert the information from selected list. Simple loop to do akk the insert commands neatly.
ranking = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
ranking_list_number = 0
name_list_number = 0
description_list_number = 0
for information in range(10):
    db_view.execute('''INSERT INTO top_ten VALUES ("'''+ date[0] +'''","''' + ranking[ranking_list_number] + ''' ","''' + NYT_names[name_list_number] +'''","'''+ description[description_list_number] +'''");''')
    ranking_list_number = ranking_list_number+1
    name_list_number = name_list_number +1
    description_list_number = description_list_number +1

#Commit changes
top_ten_db.commit()
#Close the database
db_view.close()
top_ten_db.close()
```

Note that the variables *"date", "NYT_names", and "description"* are all found using regex searches that source information from online websites, so I have no conrol over the input.

Also it should be noted that up until the introduction of an apostrophe the code has worked fine. Also the title of the book (if needed) is: The Clockmaker's Daughter

Comment: There are numerous examples of how to use placeholders in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should escape single quotes/apostrophes by doubling them (use `''` to denote a literal `'`):

```
db_view.execute('''INSERT INTO top_ten VALUES ("'''+ date[0] +'''","''' + ranking[ranking_list_number] + ''' ","''' + NYT_names[name_list_number] +'''","'''+ description[description_list_number].replace("'", "''") +'''");''')
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL. BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and
>   preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. ... A literal value can
>   also be the token "NULL".

Alternatively, you can use bound parameters:

```
db_view.execute('INSERT INTO top_ten VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (date[0], ranking[ranking_list_number], NYT_names[name_list_number], description[description_list_number]))
```

Comment: When running the code you provided I am now getting this error
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Just fixed the typo. Please try again now.

Comment: No, don't do that. Bind values to placeholders in a query instead of trying to embed them directly in a string. Doing so avoids wierd quoting issues, SQL injection attacks, and the like.

Comment: Thanks so much , the alternative method of binding the parameters worked and I'm no longer getting any errors.